# Не получается распаковать файл tar.xz

Tags: linux

Подскажите, пытаюсь установить wine, установил `sudo apt-get install xz-utils`
Ввожу `tar -xpJf wine.tar.xz` пишет tar -xpJf wine.tar.xz
tar (child): wine.tar.xz: Функция open завершилась с ошибкой: Нет такого файла или каталога
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Попробовал так: `tar -xpJf /home/jookoo/Загрузки/wine.tar.xz` ни чего не происходит.

Comment: Просто  `tar xf file.tar.xz`

Comment: Функция open завершилась с ошибкой: Нет такого файла или каталога
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now. Пишет тоже самое.

Comment: А что делает и показывает `unxz file.tar.xz`?

Comment: tar: Указать можно только один из параметров «-Acdtrux», «--delete» или «--test-label»
Попробуйте «tar --help» или «tar --usage» для
получения более подробного описания.
@AlexeyTen

Comment: если `tar` говорит «нет такого файла», значит такого файла нет — ошибся где-то в имени... пользуйся дополнением по tab'у, дабы избегать ошибок. ЗЫ: к делу не относится, но скорее всего ты скачал арбол с исходниками... ты уверен, ччто тебе именно это нужно?

Comment: @Jookoo без tar. Просто команда

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить: а зачем тебе понадобилось ставить wine из архива?